# Python Full Precision Division Source

Tags: python, c, division

I've been working with arbitrary-precision algorithms lately, and am exceedingly curious how Python goes about it. When I type a very large (600-1000) digits divided by another similarly large number, it just works and I love it. I have the Python source files and am okay with C, which / where in the source is the part that governs this division so I can look at it and maybe tinker with it? My end-game is number theory-type work in C.

Comment: I believe Python uses the [GMP library](http://gmplib.org/).

Comment: You want to look in `Objects/longobject.c` in the python2.x source.  I'm not sure where it is in the python3.x source

Comment: It looks to me like it's the function `l_divmod` based on the comments.

Comment: It's still [Objects/longobject.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Objects/longobject.c) in 3.x. (I'm not sure why they left the C types as `PyLongObject` and changed its Python name to `int`, instead of replacing most of the `PyIntObject` implementation with `PyLongObject` as they did for, e.g., `range`.)

Comment: @Mysticial: Python explicitly chose not to use GMP, for multiple reasons which are described… somewhere. If you want to use GMP, you can use [`gmpy2`](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/) or another wrapper I forget the name of. (There are places where Python's implementation guarantees bounded memory usage in exchange for slower performance, while GMP goes the other way, so you always need to consider the tradeoff, and test heavily.)

Comment: @abarnert Well that's surprising. I have no idea where I heard that Python uses GMP. But I probably mistaken it for another language.

Comment: Meanwhile, if you're trying to learn how to do bigness in C, you right want to read [C Interfaces and Implementations](https://sites.google.com/site/cinterfacesimplementations/), which has 3 chapters on exactly that (including complete code). The final result may not be as good as GMP, MAPM, Python, OpenSSL, etc., but it will probably be a lot easier to understand how to get there.

Answer (score 2):

The core of the implementation of `long / long` in Python 3.3 is in [`longobject.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Objects/longobject.c#l2384), as the function `x_divrem`.

The implementation is modelled after Knuth's "The Art of Computer Programming", Vol. 2 (3rd edition), section 4.3.1, Algorithm D "Division of nonnegative integers", per a comment from the source.

Comment: you are awesome. Looks like I'll be doing a lot of reading over this weekend. :)